# Object has no attribute "append"?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm working on a simplified sorting hat chatbot and using threading to handle the timing between inputs. However, when I pass l (a list) to create a thread, the type of l is now sorting_hat, so it doesn't have an attribute "append." How do I keep l a list object in input_thread?

side note: this is not a homework project. I'm a student who's working on this as a side project to teach a CS outreach class to high schoolers to increase interest in computer science. All help would be appreciated!

```py
class sorting_hat:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.gryffindor = 0
        self.ravenclaw = 0
        self.hufflepuff = 0
        self.slytherin = 0
        self.start = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.sort()

    def sort(self):
        print("Oh, you may not think I’m pretty,\n" +
              "But don’t judge on what you see,\n" +
              "I’ll eat myself if you can find\n" +
              "A smarter hat than me.\n" +
              "There’s nothing hidden in your head\n" +
              "The Sorting Hat can’t see,\n" +
              "So try me on and I will tell you\n" +
              "Where you ought to be.\n")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        self.prompt_init_response()

    def prompt_init_response(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        l = []
        t = threading.Thread(group=None, target=self.input_thread, args=(l,))
        t.start()
        flag10 = False
        flag25 = False
        while 1:
            if l:
                self.name = l[0]
                break
            elapsed = time.time() - self.start
            if elapsed > 10 and flag10 is False:
                flag10 = True
                print("Well, well, well...")
                print("Are you gonna just sit there or are you gonna introduce yourself? Name?")
            elif elapsed > 25 and flag25 is False:
                flag25 = True
                print("I'll just doze off then until you give me your name... Zzzzz")


    def input_thread(l, *args):
        print(type(l))
        name = input("Oh! A new student! What's your name?")
        l.append(name)
```

Comment: Why doesn't your `input_thread` method have a `self` parameter? Of course that's gonna cause problems...

Comment: when I added the self parameter, I got an error saying that I was giving the thread 3 arguments when it expected 2. I'm brand new to threading (never done it before) and am just piecing bits together through tutorials

Comment: You don't pass input_thread `self` when you call it though... I hope you know this. You will still just pass it `l` and `*args` and it will inherit self.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. Add `self` and it works as expected.

Comment: @Aran-Fey You can reproduce it by removing self :P.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! When I had the self parameter, I realized I had an error in a different part of the method that was causing the argument error. Adding the self parameter changed it to a list type!